# TypeScript AMD to single file on browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs, requirejs, amd

I'm using **TypeScript** and compiling it into one file to ES5 with AMD module using **grunt**.

For example I have `app.ts` :

```
import {CONFIG} from './config';
console.log(CONFIG.app)
```

And `config.ts` :

```
 export const CONFIG = {
    app      : 'MyApp'
}
```

App is the main script that needs to be executed eventually, and my build output is the following :

```
define("config", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.CONFIG = {
        app: 'MyApp'
    };
});
define("main", ["require", "exports", "config"], function (require, exports, config_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    console.log(config_1.CONFIG.app);
});
```

How am I supposed to make it runnable on a browser ?

I've tried to include require.js but have not suceeded in doing so.

I need to compile it to a single file and all the configurations need to be on the gruntfile.js becuase it will be a large scale project that will be served as a **single file**.

Also, is there a more efficient way that doesn't require a third party library to compile it all into one file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How am I supposed to make it runnable on a browser ?

You need to use the require.js runtime. AMD requires an AMD loader, require.js is the most popular option.

## More

Docs http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

## Personal

Personally I would just use commonjs with webpack : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html